# How do I read a CSV line from input and initialize each value to variables of different types? (C++)

Tags: c++, csv, iostream

Example of a line: "10,abc,2.5"

I want 10 to be set to an int, abc to be set to a Cstring, and 2.5 to be set to a float. The only header I will be using is iostream. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a known pattern? Like `int,string,float` for example??  Please ask more specific questions, Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also you could consider using Boost (library), no need to reinvent the wheel, [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/variant.html).  If you want just an example, you could read the header source code of it.

Comment: The `getline` function takes a delimiter as its 3rd argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do without much effort using the [std::basic_istream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) which allows reading into the basic c-string `char *` type and takes an optional delimiter as its third argument. Using the `','` as the delimiter, and keeping a simple counter to determine the conversion to perform. You can parse into `int`, or `double` using the `std::stoi` and `std::stod` functions. All with nothing but the `iostream` header, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAXFIELD 256

int main (void) {

    int cnt = 0;
    char field[MAXFIELD] = "";

    /* read each field delimited by ',' or '\n' */
    while (std::cin.getline (field, MAXFIELD, ',')) {
        if (cnt == 0) {     /* if count 0, convert to int */
            std::cout << "int    : " << std::stoi (field) << "\n";
            cnt++;  /* increment count */
        }
        else if (cnt == 1) {    /* if count 1, use string */
            std::cout << "string : " << field << "\n";
            cnt++;  /* increment count */
        }
        else {  /* if count 2, convert to double, reset count */
            std::cout << "double : " << std::stod (field) << "\n";
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** you should validate that the field did not exceed `MAXFIELD` characters by checking `failbit` and handling the error -- which is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "10,abc,2.5" | ./bin/iostream_cstring_csv
int    : 10
string : abc
double : 2.5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My only problem now is that the double isn't being read because there is no '\n' delimiter.

Comment: Where are the values coming from? If it is a file, then you are faced with non-POSIX line endings. Also, is this windoze or nix? (we all like to say it shouldn't matter, but....). Let me know.

Comment: @J.Fex, I'm not sure what problem you are running into. I've done some digging and additional testing, and it really shouldn't matter. For example, without a `'\n'`, it works fine here (e.g. `printf "10,abc,2.5" | ./bin/iostream_cstring_csv` gives same output). I haven't booted Win10 yet, so there may be an issue there that I haven't found.